# question about normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and if $MN=\{mn|m\in M,n\in N\}$, prove that $MN$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $MN$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

The attempt:
I tried just starting by showing that $MN$ is a subgroup of $G$. I said let $a=m_1  n_1$ for some $m_1 \in M$ and $n_1 \in N $ and let $b=m_2 n_2$ for some $m_2 \in M$ and $n_2 \in N$, and we need to show $a*b^{-1}$ $\in MN$.

So I get $a*b^{-1}$=$m_1n_1n_2^{-1}m_2^{-1}=m_1n_3m_2^{-1}$ but then I don't know how to show that this is in $MN$. Tips on this or the next part of the problem?

Comment: Now, you will need to use your hypothesis, $N$ is a normal subgroup. Recall $N$ normal in $G$ means for each $x\in G$, we have $xN=Nx$. So we have $m_1( n_3 m_2^{-1})= m_1( m_3 n_3)=m_3 n_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last line you wrote:
$$a*b^{-1}=m_1n_3m_2^{-1}=m_1m_2^{-1}m_2n_3m_2^{-1}$$

Do you see why this is $MN$?

Comment: Yep, since $m_1m_2^{-1}$ is in M and N is closed under conjugation, we have an element of MN. Thank you!

Comment: @AllisonCameron Good work :)

Answer (score 0):

$$m_1n_3m_2^{-1}=m_1m_2^{-1}(m_2n_3m_2^{-1})\in MN$$

**General Lemma:** if $\,M,N\,$ are subgroups of $\,G\,$ , $\,MN\,$ is a subgroup iff $\,MN=NM\,$ .

In particular, if $\,M\triangleleft G\,$ or$\,N\triangleleft G\,$ ,then $\,MN=NM\,$

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't see that!